# mongodb: arithemtic operations in .find()

Tags: mongodb, nosql

how can I find records where retirement subtract age is less than 10

```
db.users.insert({
  user_id: "bcd001",
  age: 56,
  retirement: 65,
  status: "A"
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options, either you use the aggregation framework, or you do something like this

```
db.users.find({$where: '(this.retirement - this.age > 10)'})
```

More on the aggregation framework (even if that seems like overkill for your case):

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/
- an ex: [MongoDB aggregation framework $subtract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744706/mongodb-aggregation-framework-subtract)

Answer (score 2):

(Consider including the `retiring` computation as part of the `User` document when you insert it (precalculate it))

You could use MapReduce as well, which can be more efficient than using `$where` depending on how you're using the results (plus, the results would be preserved). Here's an example using the MongoDB shell:

```
var map=function(){
    if (this.retirement - this.age < 10)  {
        emit(this.user_id, this.user_id, this.retirement - this.age);
    }
};

var reduce=function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
};
```

Then execute:

```
db.users.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: 'retiring' })
```

Results:

```
> db.retiring.find()
{ "_id" : "bcd001", "value" : 9 }
```

You might want to then use the incremental update pattern described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/).