# C# MongoDB filter on date range

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, mapreduce

I'm new to C# MongoDB driver, and have a question about filtering objects on date range.

My collection has lots of entries formatted as follows

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("51fa6ab684cc97132cfa4616"), 
   "startDate" : ISODate("2013-07-16T00:00:00Z"),
   "endDate" : ISODate("2013-07-26T00:00:00Z"),
   "company" : "ABC"
   "amount" : 15
}
```

I want to write a query to filter the collection based on: ("endDate" - "startDate") < 10, which means the result object should have end date less than 10 days of start date.

I tried to use MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query class, but didn't have any luck. Is it archivable with MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Where()? Because I want to chain up with other queries like:

```
var amountQuery = Query.GT("amount", 10).LT(20);
var dateRangeQuery = // Query.XXX()....
var query = Query.And(amountQuery, dateRangeQuery );
var result = collection.Find(query);
```

Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Without using a `$where` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/)) operator, you can not perform operations on the data such as comparing the value of two fields when using a traditional `find` call. If you were to use `$where`, MongoDb can not take advantage of indexes for the fields in the `$where` operation.  Further, it needs to use the JavaScript engine to execute the code, which further affects performance.

Assuming you're using MongoDb 2.4 or higher:

```
var dateRangeQuery=Query.Where(
             new BsonJavaScript("this.endDate - this.startDate < 10"))
```

However, rather than using the poorly performing `$where` operator, it's best to consider changing your data model to include fields that target the queries you'll commonly need. So, you might want to add a field with the value of the date difference.

It is possible to build this query using the aggregation framework, but it's often not the right solution for common queries and isn't currently designed to handle returning large result sets and documents (hence th name). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744706/mongodb-aggregation-framework-subtract) for example is an example that uses `$subtract`.